# Loop with egen variable name already defined

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a loop function with `egen`, but I get an error that the variable name is already defined, once it has looped once. I cannot use the `replace` command with the `rowmiss()` function. Any alternative ideas please?

```
foreach X of num 1/42 {

egen TEST=rowmiss(Day1Complete-Day`X'Complete) if Admission_Time==`X'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `egen` does not allow a `replace` option. You can find an `ereplace` command on SSC and I am generously listed as co-author, but the command is not one I use. It was posted to show that the idea was programmable and that was of interest to the other author.

But it's best to back up and ask what is the real problem here?

It seems that you want several different result variables, in which case you just need a different variable name each time around the loop. I also switch to `forval`.

```
forval X = 1/42 {

egen TEST`X' = rowmiss(Day1Complete-Day`X'Complete) if Admission_Time==`X'

}
```

The code is still puzzling on different levels:

1. Why is the same number being used for a value of `Admission_Time` and a suffix of each variable?
2. It seems that you are holding time information in different variables, a wide layout, whereas it is almost always much more efficient in Stata to hold it in different observations, a long layout.

Otherwise there is the spectre that

P1. Every new data management task with these data calls for 42 more variables. Before long, you will have hundreds of variables, and it will be really hard to keep track.

P2. This layout is not a good fit for almost any modelling command, if that is your middle- or long-term goal.

A minimal reproducible example here would give a miniature version of your data and explain the goal of the code, not just the immediate stumbling block. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One workaround may be to use `egen` for a temporary variable and use it to fill in the intended variable before eventually dropping the variables.

```
g TEST = .

forval X = 1/42 {
   egen TEST_`X' =rowmiss(Day1Complete-Day`X'Complete) if Admission_Time==`X'
   replace TEST = TEST_`X' if Admission_Time==`X'
   drop TEST_`X'
}
```

Comment: I guess you've seen my answer. The OP never came back with clarification, so quite what they are trying to do remains obscure. The specific question of how to combine  `egen` and `replace` is answerable but not the most important issue here at all, in my view.